# Session variable in powershell version 2 - net.httpWebRequest

Tags: .net, powershell, cookies, powershell-2.0

I am currently working on automating a REST call with powershell. I have a REST API which i was calling with my powershell script with Invoke-WebRequest as below.

**For logging in:-**

`Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -uri $loginUri -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded -Body $loginBody -Headers @{"Accept" = "application/xml"}` **-SessionVariable CookieSession** -UseBasicParsing

In the above the URL is something like Server/_Login and in the body, my credentials are passed as

```
$loginBody = "username=$username&password=$password"
```

I was getting the cookie (JSESSIONID) from this call and then parse the same to all other calls. For example

**My Logout looks like this:-**

`Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -uri $logOutUri -ContentType application/xml -Headers @{"Accept" = "application/xml"}` **-WebSession $SessionVariable** -UseBasicParsing

where urL is Server/_Logout and using -WebSession i am parsing the cookie

The problem is, i have to make this compatible with powershell version 2 and hence has to use `[System.Net.HttpWebRequest]`

So i need a function to first login which will return me the sessioncookie and then i have to parse that cookie for all other calls.

**Below is what i started with but dont know what further:-**

```
function Http-Web-Request([string]$method,[string]$Accept,[string]$contentType, [string]$path,[string]$post)
{



    $url = "$global:restUri/$path"

    $CookieContainer = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer

    $postData = $post

    $buffer = [text.encoding]::ascii.getbytes($postData)

    [System.Net.HttpWebRequest] $req = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest] [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $req.method = "$method"
    $req.Accept = "$Accept"
    $req.AllowAutoRedirect = $false
    $req.ContentType = "$contentType"
    $req.ContentLength = $buffer.length
    $req.CookieContainer = $CookieContainer
    $req.TimeOut = 50000
    $req.KeepAlive = $true
    $req.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 300");
    $reqst = $req.getRequestStream()
    $reqst.write($buffer, 0, $buffer.length)


        try
        {
            [System.Net.HttpWebResponse] $response = $req.GetResponse()  
            $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($response.GetResponseStream())

            $txt = $sr.ReadToEnd() 
                if ($response.ContentType.StartsWith("text/xml"))
                {
                    ## NOTE: comment out the next line if you don't want this function to print to the terminal
                    Format-XML($txt)
                }



            return $txt


        }

        catch [Net.WebException] 
        { 
            [System.Net.HttpWebResponse] $resp = [System.Net.HttpWebResponse] $_.Exception.Response  
            ## Return the error to the caller
            Throw $resp.StatusDescription
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So after doing a lot of investigation, i found out a way.

The problem what i was having was that the cookie container was getting lost between my calls. The cookie container in *.net* is stored in ***$CookieContainer***

All I had to do was while creating the cookie container, I had to make it *Global*

```
$global:CookieContainer = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer
```

Then During my first call which is to Login, assign the same as the cookie container

```
$req.CookieContainer = $CookieContainer
```

So, during the login, when the same is succeeded, your variable $cookiecontainer is stored with the value and all the following calls to the Rest has the same cookie container

> $req.CookieContainer = $CookieContainer

You can simply keep using **this** till you close your session.

Comment: Thats pretty nice way. A little bit of modification on the answer keeping the context same.